# Automating App Deployment in Azure with LocalResource

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles

I'm currently attempting to automate the deployment of an application to an Azure Worker role by pulling a file into the role from blob storage and working with it via a batch script, also located in blob storage.  I'm using onStart to accomplish this.  Here's a reduced version of my onStart method:

Getting ready to pull the files down:

```cs
public override bool OnStart()
        {
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

container.CreateIfNotExist();

CloudBlob file = container.GetBlobReference("file.bat");
```

Actually getting the files into the role:

```cs
LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("localStore");
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(localResource.RootPath, "file.bat");

using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@filePath)) 
            {
                file.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            }
```

This is how I get the batch file and the dependencies into the role.  My problem now is - originally, I built the batch file with the assumption that the other files would be dropped right on `C:\`.  For example - `C:\installer.exe`, `C:\archive.zip`, etc.  But now the files are in localStorage.

I'm thinking I can either A) Somehow tell the batch file where localStorage is by dynamically writing the script onStart, or B) change localStorage to use `C:\`.

I'm not sure how to do either, or what the best thing to do here would be.  Thoughts?

Comment: Another possibility would be to pass the path to local storage as input to the batch file. e.g. if I have a batch file called mycmd.bat like the one below:

=============
ECHO %1
=============

If I call mycmd.bat "C:\Program Files", it will just print "C:\Program Files" on the console.

Answer (score 1):

I would not change the LocalStorage to use C: (how would you do this anyways?). Take a look at Steve's blogpost: [Using a Local Storage Resource From a Startup Task](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-a-local-storage-resource-from-a-startup-task). He explains how you can get a LocalResource using powershell (and even call that script from a batch file).

And why not use the [Windows Azure Bootstrapper](http://bootstrap.codeplex.com/)? This is a little tool that can help you with the configuration of your role without having to write any code, you simply call it from a startup task and it can download files (also from blob storage like you're doing), work with local resources, ...

```
bootstrapper.exe -get http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/1/F31EF055-3C46-4E35-AB7B-3261A303A3B6/AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe -lr $lr(temp) -run $lr(temp)\AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe -args /q
```

**Note:** Instead of using absolute references in your batch file, make it use relative paths using %~dp0